# Como puedo crear un badget de instagram para mi pagina web?

Tags: javascript, web, instagram-api

Estoy comenzando a crear mi web y quisiera saber como podría poner el icono de instagram en mi pagina para que al darle click vaya a mi perfil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pureba esto cambiando el link a instagram por el link de tu perfil y la url de la imagen por una en tu servidor:

```html
<a href="https://instagram.com">
    <img src='https://www.adelanteconcarlos.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/instagram-png-icon-5a3aafc62af570.341760101513795526176.jpg' width="50px"/>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas agregar un enlace a tu perfil de instagram a un icono o imagen en tu web.

```
<a href="https://instagram.com/perfil">
  <img src="icono.png">
</a>
```